# Question about removing from a list when orphanRemoval is set to true without CASCADE in JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "member_id")
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "member_id")
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Child> childList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addChild(Child child){
        childList.add(child);
        child.setParent(this);
    }
}
```

testCode

```
@Test
@Transactional
@Rollback(value = false)
void name() {
    Child child1 = new Child();
    child1.setName("child1");

    Parent parent = new Parent();
    parent.addChild(child1);

    em.persist(parent);
    em.persist(child1);

    em.flush();
    em.clear();

    Parent findParent = em.find(Parent.class, parent.getId());

    findParent.getChildList().remove(0);
    //em.remove(findParent);
}
```

log

```
Hibernate: 
    /* insert for
        com.example.jpa.domain.Parent */insert 
    into
        parent (name) 
    values
        (?)
Hibernate: 
    /* insert for
        com.example.jpa.domain.Child */insert 
    into
        child (name,parent_id) 
    values
        (?,?)
Hibernate: 
    select
        p1_0.member_id,
        p1_0.name 
    from
        parent p1_0 
    where
        p1_0.member_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        c1_0.parent_id,
        c1_0.member_id,
        c1_0.name 
    from
        child c1_0 
    where
        c1_0.parent_id=?
```

I am currently a student studying JPA. While studying orphan removal settings, I've noticed that when I don't set the CASCADE, removing the parent object itself deletes the child object in the actual database. However, when I remove the child from the parent's list, JPA doesn't seem to detect the change.

From what I've learned, a child object should be removed when the association between parent and child is broken. So, when I remove the child from the parent's list, why isn't the child's data being deleted? Is it because, without the CASCADE setting, operations on the parent object don't reach the child object? Or is this a bug? I need an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a one-to-many relation between parent and child entities. Each entity is assumed to be a component that will have independent existence. Let's take a real-life example of a one-to-many relationship between a Person and Car. One person can have many cars, Suppose the person owning the car passes away, we will remove his data from the database but the cars owned by him will remain and will continue to be tracked, looking the other way when a car owned by him is sold to another user or worst case scrapped because it was not maintained properly the record corresponding to the particular car has to be deleted while the user should remain in the database. unless you explicitly set the cascade type, the operations will not be propagated to the child entities. Please do comment if this does not help you understand.

Comment: Would it be appropriate for me to interpret that it's standard behavior for the removal from the parent list to not reflect in the database due to the absence of CASCADE propagation? Furthermore, am I correct in understanding that in order to propagate removals from a collection, the CASCADE setting is essential?

Comment: yes, that's right. Please upvote this answer if you found it helpful. Also, let me give you an example where the removal of the child entity along with the parent is necessary. Suppose you have a book review system a book has a one-to-many relation with a review entity. If a book is removed from the library there is no use keeping the user reviews in the system. Such cases require a cascade. https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-how-to-delete-child-entities/